# i have defined initialized several attributes in sub class also(with same name and same datatype), but result was 0 for some of attributes

Tags: java, inheritance, attributes, final

the following code i have inherited subclass from super class and i have initialized same attribute with same types and access modifiers in the sub class also. but the output shows 0 for i already initialized values attributes. i want to know the exact reason for that.

```
class Super {
    int a = 10;
    private int b = 30;
    final int c = 30;
    static int d = 40;
    final static int e = 50;

    void printValues() {
        System.out.print("Super : ");
        System.out.println(+a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e);
    }

    Super() {
        printValues();
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    int a = 100;
    private int b = 300;
    final int c = 300;
    static int d = 400;
    final static int e = 500;

    void printValues() {
        System.out.print("Sub : ");
        System.out.println(+a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e);
    }
}

class TwentyFIve {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Sub();
    }
}
```

i expected the result for the above code as follows;
Sub : 100 300 300 400 500
but i got the output as follows;
Sub : 0 0 300 400 500

Comment: why do you hide the variables of your super class in your subclass?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `printValues` and run under the debugger. Have a look at the stack when you hit the breakpoint. When do you expect instance variables of `Sub` to be initialised?

Comment: recently i am studying the OOP in java. in inheritance , the sub class hiding the Attributes of the super class (as i know). but i wanted to know that what if we initialized the same attribute with same properties in the sub class. but i have got 0 for the attributes a and b i have already initialized in the super class and the subclass. i just wanted to know that why i have got  zero for both a and b.

Comment: @KDPKKasthurisinghe the print method is called before your sub class is done instantiating, since it's called from the super constructor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are already printing the values before your object has been completely constructed (as pointed out in a comment from @tgdavies). When single-stepping through your program (your IDE can do that), you'll see that the `printValues()` is done before the `Sub` class has a chance to initialize its fields.

As a rule of thumb, avoid "doing" anything inside a constructor. Especially, in a constructor don't call a method that can be overridden by some subclass, as this method will see a partially-empty instance.

Remove the `printValues();` call from the `Super()` constructor and place it into your `main()` method like

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Sub sub = new Sub();
    sub.printValues();
}
```

Then, you'll see the fully-initialized state of your instance.

By the way, for educational purposes it's good to sometimes break the best-practices rules (having fields with the same name in superclass and subclass), just to see how much confusion arises from that. The learning effect should be not to do that in production code.

And by the way, you should delete the superfluous `+` at the beginning of `+a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e`.